# Retrieve next Id from table using specific id from same table

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am working on Blog, If user chooses to read Full Post from home page, it redirects to Details page where only one post gets displayed with all details, where all data being displayed from database table.

What I want to implement is, user can redirect to next post from Details page only, using NEXT button placed at bottom of Details page.
I have Post ID in  in Querystring. Now I want NEXT post's ID so I can redirect user to Next post.

Please help me to retrieve Next ID from table using specific ID.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So get the post id from the query string and then just add +1.What are you struggling with?

Comment: I can't use +1, because there could be skipped numbers in PostId as posts can be deleted from Admin panel. What I want is next row's PostId from table.

Comment: Ok so then store the current post id somewhere and write a lambda expression or a LINQ query to retrieve the top 1 records where id > current page(order by ascending)

Comment: I am bit new in development. I want your help.
For e.g. If my Post id in Querystring is lke PID=34, then how would I write LINQ Query so I can get the next value?

Comment: Thanks @Denis Wessels :) I got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableBlog WHERE TableBlogId > PostId AND IsDeleted = 0
```

Comment: Wow :) , That's exactly what I wanted, Thanks a lot Jeremy :)